# Passing a uint to shader changes its value

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to pass a uint to my shader but I must be doing something wrong because in the shader the value is 3212836864 and not 4294967295.

I have a Vertex array that I store each vertex in before sending them to the shader using `glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(Vertex) * 4 * vertexBufferArrayInserts, vertexBufferArray);`

These are my `glVertexAttribPointer` calls:

```
    shaderPosAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glVertexAttribPointer(shaderPosAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderPosAttrib);

    shaderTexCoordAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texCoord");
    glVertexAttribPointer(shaderTexCoordAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, texCoords));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderTexCoordAttrib);

    shaderColorAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
    glVertexAttribPointer(shaderColorAttrib, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, color));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderColorAttrib);
```

And this is the Vertex struct

```
struct Vertex
{
    Vector2<GLfloat> position;
    Vector2<GLfloat> texCoords;
    GLuint color;

    Vertex() {

    }

    Vertex(Vector2<GLfloat> position, Vector2<GLfloat> texCoords, GLuint color) {
        this->position = position;
        this->texCoords = texCoords;
        this->color = color;
    }
};
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 150

in vec2 position;
in vec2 texCoord;
in uint color;

out vec2 TexCoord;
out uint Color;

uniform mat4 projMat;

void main()
{
    TexCoord = texCoord;
    Color = color;
    gl_Position =  projMat * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 150

in vec2 TexCoord;
in uint Color;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    float colorr = 0;

    if(Color == 3212836864)
        colorr = 1;

    outColor = texture(tex, TexCoord) * vec4(colorr, colorr, colorr, 1.0);
}
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong somewhere but I just can't see it... Help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `glVertexAttribPointer` does specify **floating point** data, so you must access them as `float`/`vec` in the shader. The `normalized` parameter of that function just specifies it the resulting floats will be normalized to [0,1] or just directly converted. In theory, you could use unnormalized uints as you do, and just use `in float color` in the shader - but you will be losing precision.

If you want to directly pass integral values to the shader, you have to use [`glVertexAttribIPointer`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml), which was originally introduced in the [`EXT_gpu_shader4`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/gpu_shader4.txt) extension  and is part of GL core since version 3.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know glVertexAttribPointer was only for floats. I packed RGBA into the uint, that's why I want to send it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this

```
struct Vertex
{
    Vector2<GLfloat> position;
    Vector2<GLfloat> texCoords;
    GLuint color;

    Vertex() {

    }

    Vertex(Vector2<GLfloat> position, Vector2<GLfloat> texCoords, GLuint color) {
        this->position = position;
        this->texCoords = texCoords;
        this->color = color;
    }
};
```

is a problem: Between the templates and that it is a class containing class members, the exact alignment of each element within that structure is completely undetermined; add to this the possible addition of a v-table (table of virtual functions instance pointers). `Vertex2` itself is probably another class or templated structure without exact alignment. Using `offsetof` you're going to see only where the instance data structure of `Vertex2` starts, but not where the variables inside it are.

When it comes to interfacing with foreign APIs (by which I mean everything that's not been compiled with the very same compiler as your own project) **or** flat memory locations classes and templates are your worst enemy.

What you actually need are *packed* structures. Don't use classes; there's just too much of an incentive to derive from them and add virtual functions which will completely mess things up. Add syntactic sugar by using global scope binary operators.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. So I should skip the Vector2 class and maybe replace it with a struct without a template. Would I use `#pragma pack` to pack my struct? 

From what I've read packing shouldn't affect this (the struct) since they're a bunch of floats and ints and they are already 32 bits so no padding would be added. Or maybe I don't fully understand it

Comment: @Semicolon: If packing happens or not depends on the compiler and the target architecture. But you're right: Padding is very unusual to happen on 32bit wide types. As of how to actually pack the structs, this depends on the compiler used. In GCC it's `__attribute__((packed))` (yes, double braces), in MSVC it's `#pragma packed`. However when it comes to flat APIs, personally I skip the structs alltogether and use arrays. See my [→linmath.h](https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h) for example.